# Handling the Post event on Google Interactive post

Tags: google-plus

I use Google Interactive post to let the logged in user invite external users to the site. I would like to register the invite on my site only once the user has chosen to post to one of his connections on google plus.

Is there a way to handle to the post event and know whether the user has posted or not and invoke a handler accordingly?

Here's how I call it today.

```
var options = {
    contenturl: myurl,
    clientid: googleappid,
    cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
    prefilltext: text,
    calltoactionlabel: "START",
    calltoactionurl: somethingstring,
    recipients: connectionid,
    onClick: doSomethingOnClick(),
};  
gapi.interactivepost.render('submit', options);
```

Just like the onClick is there some event like onPost that is supported?

Answer (score 0):

There's

```
onshare: function(response){
        console.log('callback done');
      // These are the objects returned by the platform
      // When the sharing starts...
      // Object {status: "started"}
      // When sharing ends...
      // Object {action: "shared", post_id: "xxx", status: "completed"} 
    }
```

It's undocumented, but I just tested it and it worked.